# Is there a way to increase the gold gained in selling to merchants?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have noticed you very rarely get anymore than 50 gold from selling something to the merchants. I was wondering if there was a way to increase the amount you get from them, or do they give you very low amounts throughout the entire game regardless of difficulty?

Comment: Thank you rapida, from here on out you are my proof reader haha.

Comment: No problem, I'm helping to make the internet a better place

Comment: haha indeed you are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

White items never really appreciate in value (even on Inferno, you're likely to get a massive 10 gold from selling them) - but magic items are worth substantially more as their required level increases. By late Hell and early Inferno, you'll find that most items command upwards of 200 gold from vendors, sometimes substantially more for weapons.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to increase the value of your items or make the merchant pay more the the items, there is only gold find that counts toward how much gold you find on looting/killing.